sql get select value usage
I want to use SELECT clause inside the VALUES like this: The point is to get a random value from another table
 VALUES (SELECT x FROM seq_data ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;, ...)

Yet this returns an error,
Otherwise I have to set variable and the execution becomes so slow like that
 SELECT @id := x FROM seq_data ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;
 VALUES(@id, ... )

What is the solution around this?

Trigger? Check constraint?

need to get a random integer and insert to two tables

If you use a subquery in place of a scalar value, you must put it in parentheses:
INSERT ...
VALUES ((SELECT x FROM seq_data ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1), ...);
        ^                                              ^

Also: don't use a semicolon (;) inside a subquery. Only use a semicolon at the end of the whole statement.

Use INSERT .. SELECT:
INSERT INTO table1 (col_1, col_2, ..., col_N)
SELECT x, 'literal 2', ..., 'literal N'
FROM seq_data  
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;

